# Do card/miniature packs (Pokemon, Magic, etc.) or similar fall under gambling laws?

Tags: gambling

I'm in the process of creating a game that I want to run on Kickstarter and hopefully sell after from a website and eventually in store (long term goals). The purchasers will receive a pack of miniatures (perhaps closer to cards?) of random rarity, stats, etc.

While discussing this with a friend he mentioned that this may be considered gambling and that he had heard of lawsuits toward big card companies because they hadn't disclosed the odds of getting certain pieces.

Is this a real legal issue? If so what must you disclose to be covered?